# Java: Error with constructors and passing variables

Tags: java, date, variables, constructor

I am trying to input a date in the format `dd mm yyyy` and have to return in the format e. g. `Tuesday, 29th September`. I'm new to Java and am not sure if my values from the day, month, year classes are being returned to the main. There is an error for the `Date date1 = new Date(day1, month1, year1)` saying it is undefined and to make it a constructor. If I make it a constructor and run the program I get values back like `lab2.Day@659e0bfd`. Not sure where to go from here.

```
package lab2;

public class Calendar {

//assume all months have 30 days and that 1 January is a Monday;

public static void main(String[] args) { // e.g. input: 29 09 2015

    int in1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int in2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int in3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    Day day1 = new Day(in1, in2); // string
    Month month1 = new Month(in2); // string
    Year year1 = new Year(in3); // integer


     Date date1 = new Date(day1, month1, year1); //

    date1.printName(); // e.g. "The date is Tuesday, 29th of September, 2015

}
}
```

---

```
package lab2;

public class Day {
private int day;
private int month;
private int code;
private String name; //e.g. Tuesday 

public Day(int dy, int mth ){
    day = dy;
    month = mth;
    code = ((day*month) % 7);


    // Assigning the day variable number to text //
    switch (code) {
    case 0: name = "Monday";
            break;
    case 1: name = "Tuesday";
            break;
    case 2: name = "Wednesday";
            break;
    case 3: name = "Thursday";
            break;
    case 4: name = "Friday";
            break;
    case 5: name = "Saturday";
            break;
    case 6: name = "Sunday";
            break;
    default: System.out.println("Incorrect Day Entered");}

    }

}
```

---

```
package lab2;

public class Month {

private int month1;
private String monthName;




public Month(int temp1){
    month1=temp1;


switch (month1) {
case 1: monthName = "January";
        break;
case 2: monthName = "February";
        break;
case 3: monthName = "March";
        break;
case 4: monthName = "April";
        break;
case 5: monthName = "May";
        break;
case 6: monthName = "June";
        break;
case 7: monthName = "July";
        break;
case 8: monthName = "August";
        break;
case 9: monthName = "September";
        break;
case 10: monthName = "October";
        break;
case 11: monthName = "November";
        break;
case 12: monthName = "December";
        break;
default: System.out.println("Incorrect Month Error");}


}

}
```

---

```
package lab2;

public class Year {

private int yearNumber;

public Year(int temp2)
{
    yearNumber=temp2;


}
}
```

---

```
package lab2;

public class Date {

private String day;
private String month;
private int year;



 public Date(String temp1, String temp2, int temp3){
    day = temp1;
    month = temp2;
    year = temp3; 
    }



public void printName() {
    System.out.println("The date is " +day+ ", " +month+ ", " +year);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this Question belongs on the [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> There is an error for the "Date date1 = new Date(day1, month1, year1)"
>   saying it is undefined and to make it a constructor.

Since there is no such parameterised constructor in `Date` class like `Date(Day d, Month m, Year y)`. Its having constructor `Date(String temp1, String temp2, int temp3)`. So parameter types are different.

Instead of

```
Date date1 = new Date(day1, month1, year1);
```

use

```
Date date1 = new Date(day1.name, month1.monthName, year1.yearNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is an error for the "Date date1 = new Date(day1, month1,
>   year1)" saying it is undefined and to make it a constructor. If I make
>   it a constructor and run the program I get values back like
>   "lab2.Day@659e0bfd". Not sure where to go from here.

You are getting lab2.Day@659e0bfd because you haven't implemented toString() method. Implement toString() method in your Day, Month and Year class and you'll get the desired result. Check the code below-

```
 public class Day {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int code;
    private String name; //e.g. Tuesday 

    public Day(int dy, int mth ){
        day = dy;
        month = mth;
        code = ((day*month) % 7);


        // Assigning the day variable number to text //
        switch (code) {
        case 0: name = "Monday";
                break;
        case 1: name = "Tuesday";
                break;
        case 2: name = "Wednesday";
                break;
        case 3: name = "Thursday";
                break;
        case 4: name = "Friday";
                break;
        case 5: name = "Saturday";
                break;
        case 6: name = "Sunday";
                break;
        default: System.out.println("Incorrect Day Entered");}

        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

    }
```

Similary, you can put the toString() method in Month class

```
public class Month {

private int month1;
private String monthName;




public Month(int temp1){
    month1=temp1;


switch (month1) {
case 1: monthName = "January";
        break;
case 2: monthName = "February";
        break;
case 3: monthName = "March";
        break;
case 4: monthName = "April";
        break;
case 5: monthName = "May";
        break;
case 6: monthName = "June";
        break;
case 7: monthName = "July";
        break;
case 8: monthName = "August";
        break;
case 9: monthName = "September";
        break;
case 10: monthName = "October";
        break;
case 11: monthName = "November";
        break;
case 12: monthName = "December";
        break;
default: System.out.println("Incorrect Month Error");

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return monthName;
        }

}
```

Your Year class -

```
public class Year {

private int yearNumber;

public Year(int temp2)
{
    yearNumber=temp2;


}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return yearNumber;
        }
}
```